# Почему члены предложения делятся на главные и второстепенные?

Tags: члены-предложения

Почему члены предложения делятся на главные и второстепенные?

Answer (score 1):

Основной функцией слов и словосочетаний является НАЗЫВНАЯ  функция.

Предложение отличается от слова или словосочетания ПРЕДИКАТИВНОСТЬЮ - иначе говоря, отнесенностью к действительности с точки зрения реальности и времени.

Предикативный признак (реальность и время) выражает сказуемое, а подлежащее в двусоставном предложении является  носителем предикативного признака. Подлежащее и сказуемое составляют предикативную основу предложения, поэтому они называются гласными членами предложения.

Нераспространенное предложение состоит только их главных членов, а распространенное включает также второстепенные члены. Второстепенные члены являются ПРИСЛОВНЫМИ РАСПРОСТРАНИТЕЛЯМИ главных членов или других второстепенных членов.

Answer (score 0):

Без главных членов нет предложения. Ну, хотя бы один главный обязательно должен быть.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет главных то это не предложение. Поэтому они называются главными. А второстепенные их дополняют. Без них может быть предложение. Поэтому они делятся они ведь разные.

Comment: «Поэтому они делятся они ведь разные.» Это предложение, если делится, то — в каком месте?

Comment: На любые вопросы даем *любые* ответы? На самом деле это стоит сохранить, чтоб неповадно было такие вопросы задавать.)))